# Docker- Any way to provide multiple USB device Access (Not using --privilaged)?

Tags: docker

Is there any way that the docker environment could be given to multiple USB devices, say `/dev/video0, /dev/video4 and /dev/ttyUSB4`?

In case of a single device, it could be

```
docker run -t -i --device=/dev/ttyUSB4 ubuntu bash
```

and for multiple devices

```
docker run -t -i --privileged -v /dev/bus/usb:/dev/bus/usb ubuntu bash
```

But I needed to know if there is anyway I could provide access like in the former case to specific devices alone (Not using privilages mode).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Docker works with `device` option as an array. So,
you can specify several devices also with `device` option:

```
docker run -ti --device=/dev/ttyUSB4 --device=/dev/video0 --device=/dev/video4 ubuntu bash
```

In docker-compose is also possible:

**docker-compose.yml**

```
...
services:
  myservice:
    ...
    devices:
    - "/dev/ttyUSB4:/dev/ttyUSB4"
    - "/dev/video0:/dev/video0"
    - "/dev/video4:/dev/video4"
```

There's another possibility giving linux capability, but it's unrecommended (dangerous like privileged mode) for production: FOWNER capability:

```
docker run -ti --cap-add=FOWNER ubuntu bash
```

Nevertheless, in kubernetes, for example, it's not enough and you need privileged mode.